# SQL: Get multiple values in same Table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a Table which contains more than 1 parameters for the same ID:

```
id      identifier_id   ts                  name        int_value
6117    12              2020-02-25 11:44:40 Enable      0
6118    12              2020-02-25 11:44:40 Limit1      600000
6119    12              2020-02-25 11:44:40 Limit2      800000
6115    12              2020-02-25 11:44:40 Reset       0
6116    12              2020-02-25 11:44:40 TimePeriod  604800
16648   12              2020-02-28 06:36:50 Enable      1
16778   12              2020-02-28 09:31:19 Limit1      15
16779   12              2020-02-28 09:31:19 Limit2      25
```

What i need is for identifier_id (here 12) i want to get `Limit1` and `Limit2` and the `int_values`for these names. With the latest `ts`.
My Result should look like this:

```
id      identifier_id   Limit1_value    Limit2_value
16778   12              15              25
```

Im searching and trying since hours but havent found anything that worked for me.

Comment: do you need id in your result ? How is it defined as one row in the result corresponds to 2 rows in the input.

Comment: is id a primary key (unique value)?  How is it known that 16778 and 16779 go together?   Do you need to answer this for other pairs of rows?  In general, how is know that a particular pair go together?

Comment: id in this is irrelevant identifier_id is what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the id column
(assuming your table is named parameters):

```
with params as (
  select distinct identifier_id
    from parameters)
select params.identifier_id,
       (select int_value from parameters p where p.identifier_id = params.identifier_id and p.name = 'Limit1' order by p.ts desc limit 1) as Limit1,
       (select int_value from parameters p2 where p2.identifier_id = params.identifier_id and p2.name = 'Limit2' order by p2.ts desc limit 1) as Limit2
from params
```

Comment: Thank you very much just what i needed.